# How to create a SSH tunnel to RDS through EC2 which is accessed via an ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, aws-application-load-balancer

I am relatively new to AWS so any help would be greatly appreciated!

The problem I am having is that I cannot establish a SSH tunnel to a RDS database through an EC2 instance because an ALB only allows HTTPS/HTTP, not SSH.

I have a public VPC which contains:

1. A MySQL RDS instance in a private subnet
2. EC2 instance in a private subnet(s)
3. Application Load Balancer (ALB) in a public subnet

N.B. I setup the ALB and EC2 instance via Elastic Beanstalk

Is it possible to establish a SSH tunnel through the ALB or is there another route which is recommended, I have done some research and both SSM or a bastion host seem to be common?

The image below shows the details required in order to connect to the MySQL database over SSH:

[image: MySQL Workbench SSH connection setup]

Comment: Do you mean you want to connect to the server running your SQL server, or to connect to the SQL server itself? The former is impossible, the latter not particularly hard.

Comment: I believe I would like to connect to the MySQL server itself so I can make changes to the database.  Previously I did this through an EC2 instance which was in a public subnet.

Comment: No, because ALB uses only HTTP and HTTPS protocols, not SSH protocol. You need to use network load balancer, if you want to use SSH through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use SSH Port Forwarding by connecting to the EC2 instance (via SSH) and then forward some ports via that instance to connect to the Amazon RDS database.

However, this will not work with an EC2 instance in a private subnet. You would need to launch an EC2 instance in a **public subnet** to be accessible from the Internet.

An alternate method would be to [Use port forwarding in AWS Systems Manager Session Manager to connect to remote hosts | AWS Cloud Operations & Migrations Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/use-port-forwarding-in-aws-systems-manager-session-manager-to-connect-to-remote-hosts/):

[image: Port forwarding in AWS Systems Manager Session Manager]

This uses the **Systems Manager agent** installed on the **private EC2 instance** to establish a connection with the AWS Systems Manager service. This allows you to connect to a private instance. It acts like SSH but it isn't actually using SSH.

As part of this connection you can **specify port forwarding** so that traffic can be sent across the Session Manager connection to the Amazon RDS database in the same VPC as the EC2 instance.

I think this method would suit your situation nicely. You would need to add some permissions to the IAM Role on the EC2 instance to allow Session Manager to operate.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  You mentioned SSM "acts like SSH but is isn't actually", does this mean I do not need to allow SSH on port 22 for the EC2 instance?

Comment: That is correct. The agent installed on the EC2 instance creates an _outbound_ connection to the AWS Systems Manager service. Since Security Groups are _stateful_, this allows return traffic to reach the private instance without requiring any Inbound rules. So, there is no need for an inbound rule for SSH. **It does, however, require a NAT Gateway** (or NAT instance) in a public subnet to give the private EC2 instance outbound access to the Internet.